# How can I get my (Arduino) Pro Micro schematic to allow me to program it through GPIO instead of USB

Tags: power, pins, bootloader

I'm trying this project so far I've got the schematic of a Pro Micro, which is powered through GPIO from a Raspberry Pi Zero, and want to remove the micro usb connection and able to flash it using an avr programer and a few pins.

How do I get to Achieve that? also the Pro Micro is getting D+/D- from the the raspberry's D+/D- pads as well. Schematic below for reference. 
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can program Pro Micro with programmer.

Comment: you cannot power the board through GPIO pins ... those are for input/output only

Comment: if Micro is connected to PI with USB, you can use it for serial upload to Micro from PI with avrdude.

Comment: I would like to understand what you want to build. PI has GPIO so why to attach a Micro?

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what you mean by this: *"flash it using an avr programer and a few pins"*, and why you want to do that.

Comment: It's unfortunate m1gu3 wouldn't bother to answer my question. I believe I might provide a useful answer. In the latest avrdude 6.3.0-arduino14 from Arduino, a `linuxspi` programmer option was added. This allows you to use an RPi as an ISP programmer. You can find a general overview in the 2nd half of https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-stand-alone-programmer and some more technical discussion at: https://github.com/per1234/Arduino_Boards/pull/1. Currently it only works if run as superuser. That bug should be fixed in the next avrdude release, after which I will release a package.

Comment: @per1234, thanks for getting back at me with this. Actually the whole goal of the project is to have this arduino compatible board that can house a button matrix, screen, battery and raspberry pi, such like the PocketChip. I want to avoid having this particular USB for the arduino part since the power supply will have a usb for charging. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to arduino.stackexchange.
You can program your ATmega32U4 on at least two ways:
1. Use Arduino's bootloader and D+/D- pins. This way you won't need an external programmer. Try search for phase "programming ATmega32U4 with bootloader".
2. Use ISP (In-System-Programming) method. In this case you can use your avr programmer. To do so you also need access to PINs named Reset, MISO, MOSI, SCLK. See [this link](https://www.coreforge.com/blog/2014/09/recovering-arduino-pro-micro-atmega32u4/) or [this one](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/atmega32u4-programming)

As always, the important read is [ATMega32U4 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: Awesome, links and everything. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you buy a pi zero to USB  add-on board? 
You can stack the pi on top and plug it into a normal female USB port on your computer.

The USB board has some pins that connect to the solder points of the mini USB, so you can delete all the connectors you won't need.

Other option is to solder a wire to the pi and extend the connector with a cable.

I'm not shire, if you can program the pi true its serial pins.
USB is a serial connection after all. So I think this should be possible

Comment: Hey @DAM, your idea sounds very doable but the main concept of this project is to have a mobile rPi, I want to flatten it most I can. But thanks for your input I might use some of those ideas too!

Answer (score 0):

An avr programmer uses the ISP interface to program a chip. For this you need the pins for MOSI, MISO, SCK and Reset. Of course you have also to provide power to the board through Vcc and ground.

I'm not sure, if it's OK to keep the USB connection while programming via ISP, but since you want to remove that connection either way, this isn't a problem for you. You can remove the USB connection completely (no D+ or D- connection).

Note: when you are programming the Arduino Micro via ISP without also burning the bootloader, you won't be able to use USB for programming anymore, until you burn the bootloader again.

Comment: Sounds good, so basically a 4 pin header with MOSI, MISO, SCK and RST will do the trick. And yeah its exchanging data with the rPI without the USB plug I guess. Sorry not an expert on this kind of things, thanks!

Comment: Depending in the voltage, that the Micro runs on, you may need a level shifter, so that nothing gets damaged due to too high voltage